# Let $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb{R}\,\cup\,\{+\infty\}$ be a map. Then, for $x_0\in X,\;f(x_0)\geq \sup\limits_{V\in U(x_0)}\inf\limits_{x\in V}f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:X\rightarrow \Bbb{R}\,\cup\,\{+\infty\}$ be a map where $X$ is a real normed space. Then, for an arbitrary $x_0\in X,$ I want to prove that the following always holds:

\begin{align}f(x_0)\geq \sup\limits_{V\in U(x_0)}\inf\limits_{x\in V}f(x)
\end{align}

**MY TRIAL**

Let $x_0\in X,$ then $\exists\,V\in\,U(x_0)$ such that $f(x_0)\geq f(x),\;\forall\;x\in V$, where $U(x_0)$ is the set of all neighbourhoods of $x_0$. So,

\begin{align}f(x_0)\geq \inf\limits_{x\in V}f(x),\;\;\text{for some}\;\;V\in U(x_0),
\end{align}
which implies that \begin{align}f(x_0)\geq \sup\limits_{V\in U(x_0)}\inf\limits_{x\in V}f(x)
\end{align}

Kindly check if I am correct or wrong. If it happens that I'm wrong, kindly give an alternative proof. Thanks

Comment: You need to give us a hint - what is $U(x_0)$?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Sorry! $U(x_0)$ is the set of all neighbourhoods of $x_0$

Comment: @Mike Oh, so $X$ is a topological space? But why should that matter when $f$ is not necessarily continuos?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Yes! Infact, $X$ is a real normed space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not the slightest reason why $V\in U(x_0)$   with $f(x_0)\ge f(x),\forall x\in V$ should exist.

However, if $V\in U(x_0)$ then $x_0\in V$ (here, I make a wild guess  that $U(x_0)$ denotes some non-empty subset of the power set of $X$ and each of its elements contains $x_0$) and hence $\inf_{x\in V} f(x)\le f(x_0)$.